# Zeppelin: Python Interpreter Multiple Bindings Error (SLF4j, py4j)

Tags: python, java, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run this command:

```
%python
print("hello-world")
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Interpreter process is not running
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zappelin/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/interpreter/python/python-interpreter-with-py4j-0.10.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zappelin/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Is their any workaround for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In it's current form, your question is a little hard to answer. What is your current setup? Are you running your own instance of Zeppelin? Are you using a hoster? Where are you seeing the error? Unfortunately, I don't know Apache Zeppelin myself, hence, I won't be able to answer your question, but someone else might. Cheers :)